# Finding bounded harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find bounded harmonic functions $h$ in $H:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y>0\}$ such that $h(x,0)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

I'm unsure how to approach this. The context is that this is straight after we are given the following  theorem.

**Thm.** Suppose that $\Omega$ is a domain, that $f:\Omega\rightarrow\Upsilon$ is holomorphic, and that $h:\Upsilon\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is harmonic. Write $f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u,v$ are real valued functions and let $F(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ be the corresponding vector-valued function.
Then $h\circ F$ is harmonic in $\Omega$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Find a holomorphic bijection from $H$ to the unit disk. Finding the bounded harmonic functions on the disk with boundary values equal to $1$ is easy (either separate variables or use the Poisson integral).

Answer (score 1):

We extend $h$ to $H^-:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y<0\}$ in the following way: for any $y>0$, let
$$h(x,-y):=2-h(x,y)$$
The extended map is a bounded harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hence, by the [Liouville Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville.27s_theorem), $h$ is the constant map $1$.

However for any $0<r<1$, it is possible to find a non-constant bounded harmonic functions $h$ in $H:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y>0\}\setminus B((1,0),r)$ such that $h(x,0)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography) 
$$x+iy=z\to C(z):=\frac{z-i}{z+i}=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
is an holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-i\}$ which maps the real line to the unit circle.

Now consider the function 
$$h(x,y):=g(u(x,y),v(x,y))=1+\ln(u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y))$$
where $g(x,y)=1+\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: @Twenty-six colours Any further doubt?